# iTunes Conect App Transfer

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I tried to transfer app from one account to other.

and after i sign the `Transfer Agreements Contract` the app is still in the older account and is not moved to the new account.

Any idea why it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transfer has to be approved. It will be listed in your "Contracts" section under pending. Once it's approved, it will transfer successfully. It usually happens within one business day.

Answer (score -1):

You must go in XCode click archive, then wait for the product to archive. After it has archived click export. In Itunes connect where it asks for the build, your build should come up, click it and then you are done.